# Compute $X$ and $Y$ so that $(A+uv^T)^k = A^k + XY^T$.

Tags: matrices

It is a problem from Matrix Computations ed4(P1.2.10) and I have no idea about it. The original problem is:

Suppose $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}, u\in \mathbb{R}^n$, $v\in \mathbb{R}^n$, $k \leq n$ is an integer. Show how to compute $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times k}$ and $Y \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times k}$ so that $(A+uv^T)^k = A^k + XY^T$.

Any help would be appreciated, Thank you!

Comment: The most obvious thing to do in a problem like this is consider a few small cases first. So, for instance, when $k=2$ it can easily be seen that one is attempting to 'factorize' the expression $u v^T A+A uv^T+(v^T u)uv^T.$ (I can't say I see why one exists off hand, but if you can get this case then the rest should be easier.)

Comment: Some effort to try this will be also appreciated .

Comment: It'd also be a good idea to consider what a proof by induction would look like, i.e. if $(A+u v^T)^k=A^k+XY^T$ then show that this implies $(A+uv^T)^{k+1}=A^k+X'Y'^T$ for some matrices $X',Y'$ of appropriate size.

Comment: You may employ [rank factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_factorization), just prove that $(A + uv^\top)^k = A^k + \text{ matrix of rank }k\text{ or less}$

Comment: Thank all of you, I know the existence of the factorison of $XY^T$ for any integer $k\leq n$ now. And the computation routine of $X$ and $Y$ can be derived with the induction process as @Semiclassical mentioned.